# R querying second dataframe by the range to which a numerical value in column belongs and returning the corresponding value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column with numbers ranging from 0 - 50 (column A). I have another dataframe with two columns, one column shows a numerical range (column B) and the other shows a corresponding value (column C). In the first dataframe, I would like to add a column D that is the result of finding the range (in column B) to which the value in column A belongs and returning the corresponding value (column C).

| A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 50 |

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| 0-10 | Low |
| ... | ... |
| 41-50 | High |

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Low |
| 50 | High |

Answer (score 0):

If your categories are adjacent (no gaps between ranges), `findInterval` might do the trick (replace 2nd dataframe with named lookup vector as fit). Example:

```
values = c(12, 2, 42)

## define categories by lower bound:
categories = c(low=0, middle=10, high=40)

names(categories)[
    findInterval(values, categories)
]
```